# Touch event not working in custom extend view

Tags: java, android

I have Activity.java and PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener interface. In this program I have to click on buttons (pink and blue background button) and select a shape and drag into the view area.

I need help I have been trying last few days.

```
     MainActivity.java
        package com.easyway2win;

        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.graphics.Color;
        import android.graphics.Paint;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.Button;
        import android.widget.TextView;



        public class MainActivity extends Activity {

            private Button butnPink,butnBlue;
            public PaintView paintView = null;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                butnPink = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pinkColor);
                butnBlue = (Button)findViewById(R.id.blueColor);
                View paintView = (View)findViewById(R.id.view1);
            }

            public void clickMe(View view){
                int intColor = 0;
                String hexColor = null;

                switch(view.getId()){

                case R.id.pinkColor:
                    intColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.pink);

                    hexColor = String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & intColor));
                    Log.d("Hi", "I am pink color code " + hexColor);

                    break;
                case R.id.blueColor:
                    intColor =  getResources().getColor(R.color.blue);
                  }

                PaintView paintView = new PaintView(this); 
                paintView.setPaintColour(intColor);

            }// end [ clickMe method ]
        }

package com.easyway2win;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Toast;
```

PaintView.java

```
public class PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener{

    private Paint paint;
    private Path path;

    private Bitmap buffer = null;
    private Canvas penCanvas = null;
    int colour = 0;

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        super(context);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);


            // create the Paint and set its color        
            paint = new Paint();*/

           path = new Path();
    }


    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs ){
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public PaintView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle/*Context context, Rect rectangle, Paint paint*/) {
        super(context,attrs,defStyle);
        //  this.rectangle = rectangle;
        //  this.paint = paint;

    }

    public void setPaintColour(int colour){
        paint.setColor(colour);
        //Log.d("Hi", "I am in setPaintColour Method" );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        /*  canvas.drawRect(rectangle,paint);*/
        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent evt) {

        int action = evt.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;

        switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:{
            //Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Action Down", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            //Log.d("Down", "Pointer Down");
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN : {
            Log.d("CV", "Other point down");
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP : {
            Log.d("CV", "Other point up");
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP : {
            Log.d("CV", "Pointer up");
            break;
        }

        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please describe the behavior you're getting, and how it differs from what you want to happen?  Glancing through the code with no context, I'd guess that either (A) you're getting null reference exceptions, or (B) nothing seems to change when the pink button is clicked, but my guess could be wrong.

Comment: Hi, I am moving my squre button on to the view then it gives me wired error. Please, guide me. Null pointer exception

Comment: Hi I am not getting error. Thank you. But I am not able to move square shape. Please, need your help

Answer (score 0):

The null pointer exception happens when you try to call methods on the paint object before it has been created.  The `paint = new Paint();` line needs to be moved earlier in the PaintView constructor, or paint can simply be initialized where it is declared.

```
public class PaintView extends View implements OnTouchListener{

    private Paint paint;
    // alternate: private Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Path path;

    private Bitmap buffer = null;
    private Canvas penCanvas = null;
    int colour = 0;

    public PaintView(Context context) {
        super(context);

            // create the Paint and set its color        
            paint = new Paint();*/
            // alternate: skip this line and use the alternate above

            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);




           path = new Path();
    }
```

It also looks like the PaintView is never added into your layout. The object is created, but it isn't attached to anything in the UI. If you have a reference to the ViewGroup (LinearLayout, etc.), a new View can be added to it with the `addView` method. If another View needs to be removed from the layout, use `removeView`.

Comment: Please any one can help me. I am not able to move my square shape defined in the  drawable/square.xml.